# Accessing an environment variable across nginx w/ Lua and Rails

Tags: nginx, configuration, ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, lua

I'm implementing something like [this](http://www.stavros.io/posts/writing-an-nginx-authentication-module-in-lua/) to let one service allow access to separate upstream service in nginx.

Briefly: A Rails app sets an HMAC cookie, which is then checked by some Lua code thanks to an `access_by_lua` directive in nginx.

To generate and verify the cookie, both Rails and nginx-Lua must of course share a secret key. I've tried setting this up as an environment variable in `/etc/environment`.

To make the var available in Rails, I had to fiddle with Unicorn's init script a bit. But at least that script is contained within the project, and just symlinked into place.

Meanwhile, to get at the variable in Lua, I do something like this: `os.getenv("MY_HMAC_SECRET")`. But in order for Lua to have access to that when running under nginx, it must first be [listed using the `env` directive](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#System_Environment_Variable_Support) in the main nginx config.

So now, I'm feeling like my configuration is being spread out all over the place:

1. in /etc/environment (outside my project)
2. in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (outside my project)
3. in unicorn's init script
4. in my site's nginx vhost config

It's starting to seem a little ridiculous just to make a simple string accessible in multiple places...

Is there a simpler way to do this? Honestly, the easiest way I can think of is hardcode it in the 2 places I need it, and be done. But that sounds nasty.

Comment: Welp, got migrated. I'll leave this up here for a bit, see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Better to put it only in the two places it's *actually* needed, in the two respective configuration files, than in the global environment where *every process* has access to it, as you have it now.

Comment: Good point. But I'd still like to define it in one place, and in a way I can keep out of source control (or at any rate override on the production server); hence why I used the global env. I just feel like there should be some simple way of achieving it.

Comment: @Flambino Put the secret in a file only readable to those users who need it. The configuration files can contain a path to that file.

Comment: @kasperd Yes, that's what I'm trying to do: Reference the secret in several places. My question is how to best do that when using env is a) too broad, b) overly complicated, and c) the config files are for very different things that won't all eat the same file types.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `init_by_lua` directive in your vhost config.

```
init_by_lua 'HMAC_SECRET = "SECRET-STRING"';
server {
    # and so on
}
```

So you'll have you secret in two places, but both in your project (if I understand correctly and vhost config is in your project).

You can even use `init_by_lua_file` and make some efforts to read and parse that file in your unicorn init.

Comment: Nice idea. I was thinking of using `init_by_lua` too, but was hoping there'd be a file format what "just worked" so neither lua or bash or ruby would have to mess around with parsing it. Looking at your example, though, it be just that simple var declaration. Interpreted by Ruby, it's a constant definition (no need to load it in the init script; just do that in the Rails app itself); in Lua it's a global. Kinda interesting, actually. Should be able to load that into either interpreter. Skip the whitespace, and a shell will eat it too, I think